# Initial data not working if I hide some one-to-many fields in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I want to prefill some one to many fields and also hide these field because I want to avoid a scenario where a user can see all the records related to the fields. The problem I'm facing is when I use '**all**' on the form fields I the initial data dictionary is working well, but if I try to use a list of the fields I want displayed, the initial data is not getting passed into the form.

Here is my models.py:

```
class Agent(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True,)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True,)
    provcoord = models.ForeignKey(Provcoord, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)
    regcoord = models.ForeignKey(Regcoord, null=True, blank=False, on_delete=SET_NULL)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False, blank=True, choices=REGION)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False, blank=False, choices=PROVINCE)
    id_no = id_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False, unique=True,)
    agent_no = models.CharField(default="Not Assigned", max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    address = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, choices=GENDER)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="assets", default="default.png")
    is_blacklisted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    reason_for_blacklist = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    registered_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("agent", kwargs={'str' :str.id})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Adult(models.Model):
   id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
   agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)
   regcoord = models.ForeignKey(Regcoord, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)
   provcoord = models.ForeignKey(Provcoord, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)
   surname = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
   other_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
   address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
   region = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True,choices=PROVINCE)
   dob = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False)
   gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, choices=GENDER)
   id_no = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
   receipt_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="Not Receipted", null=True, 
blank=True)
   phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False,)
   marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, choices=MARITAL_STATUS)
```

views.py:

```
def add_parent(request,):
    agent = request.user.agent
    regcoord = request.user.agent.regcoord
    provcoord = request.user.agent.provcoord
    region = request.user.agent.region
    province = request.user.agent.province
    form = ParentForm(initial={
        'agent' :agent,
        'regcoord' :regcoord,
        'provcoord' :provcoord,
        'region' :region,
        'province' :province
    })


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ParentForm(request.POST, request.FILES,)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'form' :form}
    return render(request, 'kyc/add_adult.html', context)
```

forms.py:

```
class ParentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Adult
        fields = ['surname', 
            'first_name', 
            'other_name', 
            'address', 
            'dob', 
            'gender', 
            'id_no', 
            'receipt_no',
            'phone_no',
            'image'
         ]
```

Please Help on how I can get around this issue.

Comment: In principle when you use the `fields` list, all the fields that you have not mentioned in the list will be excluded from your form and will not be rendered with your template. And therefore the initial data of these fields will not be visible either.

Comment: Noted. Any suggestions on how I can prevent a user access the dropdown list all the records related to the fields?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach I suggest (not tested though):

```
from django import forms

class ParentForm(ModelForm):
    agent = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    regcoord = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    provcoord = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    region = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    province = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(ParentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['agent'].initial = self.user.agent
        self.fields['regcoord'].initial = self.user.regcoord
        self.fields['provcoord'].initial = self.user.provcoord
        self.fields['region'].initial = self.user.region
        self.fields['province'].initial = self.user.province

    class Meta:
        model = Adult
        fields = ['surname', 
            'first_name', 
            'other_name', 
            'address', 
            'dob', 
            'gender', 
            'id_no', 
            'receipt_no',
            'phone_no',
            'image'
         ]
```

Notes how I referenced the 5 fields (agent, regcoord, provcoord, region, province) as extra fields by declaring them as simple `CharFields`. So they are no longer rendered from the model as dropdown lists. Then in the method `__init__` I define the initial values ​​for each of the fields.

Your function add_parent should become:

```
def add_parent(request,):

    form = ParentForm(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ParentForm(request.POST, request.FILES,)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'form' :form}
    return render(request, 'kyc/add_adult.html', context)
```

**Edit**

Here is another alternative:

```
def add_parent(request,):
    data = {'agent': request.user.agent, 'regcoord': request.user.regcoord, 'provcoord': request.user.provcoord, 'region': request.user.region, 'province': request.user.province}
    form = ParentForm(initial=data)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ParentForm(request.POST, request.FILES,)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'form' :form}
    return render(request, 'kyc/add_adult.html', context)
```

In the function `add_parent`, I pass the initial values ​​in the form of a dictionary (`data`), to the variable `initial`.

Then you need to remove the `__init__` method from your form. Django will take care of rendering the form with the initial values ​​in the corresponding fields.

Comment: This is a smart solution. After having implemented it, I've encountered this error, 
    AttributeError at /add_parent
    'NoneType' object has no attribute 'agent'

Comment: @Jaks The error maybe because you are not logged in, as it is taking None instead of `user`. The solution is right.

Comment: @SunderamDubey I'm pretty sure I'm logged in because I can see the dashboard is displaying the data that is relevant to the logged in user and I've also wrapped the add_parent function with a login_required decorator.

Comment: @SunderamDubey perhaps I need to clarify on the fact that this from is no intented to create a user.

Comment: It should normally work. As indicated by @SunderamDubey the error probably comes from the fact that you are not logged in. Anyway I just edited my answer with another possible alternative